# Flex RGBA colors in CSS

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I am trying to style a DataGrid component so that the background is transparent (Flex 4). Rgba colors work fine if I make "alternatingItemColors" an attribute on the component, but if I try to declare it in my css stylesheet, I cannot declare the alpha value.

**Works (mxml):**

```
<mx:DataGrid id="songGrid" width="800" height="529" dataProvider="{songs}" itemClick="handleRowClick(event);" x="145" y="168" headerStyleName="dataGridHeader" alternatingItemColors="[0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFF]">
```

**Doesn't Work (css)**:

```
mx|DataGrid {
    alternatingItemColors: #FFFFFFFF, #FFFFFFFF;
}
```

If I enter the values as "0xFFFFFFFF", I get a parse error, because it's not proper css (of course, most of flex's css isn't proper css, but I digress...). So, is there any way to declare the alpha value of these colors in the css?

Comment: I, sadly, don't think there is. I've had to extend DataGrid / List before to get access to get the alternatingItemColors to draw the way you want. Setting backgroundAlpha doesn't get you anywhere does it?

Comment: Nope, I think the alternatingItemColors draw directly on top of the background, so the alpha doesn't matter.

Comment: So, back from vacation. It looks like Flex doesn't even handle transparency correctly. Anything other than #FFFFFFFF breaks anyways. Awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You could try extending the DataGrid and making the following override:

```
override protected function drawRowBackground(s:Sprite, rowIndex:int,
                            y:Number, height:Number, color:uint, dataIndex:int):void {
    var background:Shape = Shape(s.getChildAt(rowIndex));
    background.alpha = 0.5; // or whatever alpha value you wish
    super.drawRowBackground(s, rowIndex, y, height, color, dataIndex);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I hate having to override an object for something so simple, but I'll try this when I'm back on the project.

Answer (score -1):

CSS3 transparency is described at http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency . From the examples, where the alpha is a number between 0 (fully transparent) and 1 (fully opaque):

`em { color: rgba(100%,0%,0%,1) } /* the same, with explicit opacity of 1 */`

Comment: Yeah, flex doesn't implement css3. Thanks though.